# Utilizar el mismo objeto en dos clases diferentes

Tags: java, poo

Bien, tengo tres clases , la clase main, una clase cuentas con sus atributos y sus metodos, y una clase CuentasBO que contiene un arraylist y tiene tambien sus metodos.En la clase main creo objetos que guardo en el arraylist de CuentasBO, pero necesito referenciar a ese mismo arraylist en la clase Cuentas ya que tengo un metodo transferencia que busca la cuenta a la que se va a ingresar en ese arrayList. Entonces si yo simplemente instancio otra vez la clase CuentasBO en la clase cuentas estaria usando el arrayList pero no el mismo, por lo que cuando llamase al metodo de transferencia, no estaria buscando en el arrayList donde estan las cuentas guardadas si no en el vacio que instanciamos previamente. Hay alguna manera de referenciar a ese mismo objeto instanciado en el main en la clase cuentas para asi poder usar ese mismo arrayList en esa clase ?

```
public class CuentasBO {

private List<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();

public List<Cuenta> getCuentas() {
    return cuentas;
}

public void setCuentas(ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas) {
    this.cuentas = cuentas;
}

public List guardarCuentas(Cuenta p) throws BDException {
    if (cuentas.size() > 10) {
        throw new BDException("EL numero de cuentas almacenadas ya ha llegado a su limite (10)");
    }
    cuentas.add(p);
    return cuentas;
}

public void mostrarCuentas() {
    for (Cuenta p : cuentas) {
        System.out.println("El numero de IBAN: " + p.getIban() + ", DNI del propietario: " + p.getCliente().toString());
    }

}

public Cuenta buscarCuenta(String a) {
    Cuenta cuentaBuscada=null;
    for (Cuenta p : cuentas) {
        if (p.getIban().equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {

            cuentaBuscada = p;
        }
    }
    return cuentaBuscada;



}
}
```

la clase cuenta

```
public class CuentaPlusTransfer extends Cuenta {



@Override
public void transferencia(BigDecimal cantidad, String ibanDestino) throws MovimientoException, IbanException, CCCException {
    if (cantidad.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new MovimientoException("La cantidad a ingresar/retirar/transferir no puede ser negativa.");
    }
    if (this.getSaldo().subtract(cantidad).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new MovimientoException("La cantidad a transferir supera el saldo de la cuenta");
    }
    try {
        UtilidadesBanco.validarIBAN(ibanDestino);
        this.retirada(cantidad);
        e.buscarCuenta(ibanDestino).Ingreso(cantidad);

    } catch (IbanException | CCCException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}

}
```

en transferencia necesitaria referencia al anterior array, puedo solucionarlo usando el metodo buscarCuenta en el main y pasandole la cuenta al metodo transferencia, pero me piden hacerlo pasandole el IBAN. Te adjunto aqui al final la clase abstracta cuenta:

```
public abstract class Cuenta {

private String iban;
private Cliente cliente;
private BigDecimal saldo;

public static Cuenta getInstance(String iban, String DNI, String nombre, String tipo) throws IbanException, CCCException, DNIException, ClienteException {
    Cuenta cuenta = tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("PLUS") == true ? new CuentaPlusTransfer() : new CuentaRegalito();
    UtilidadesBanco.validarIBAN(iban);
    cuenta.setIban(iban);
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.setDNI(DNI);
    cliente.setNombre(nombre);
    cuenta.setCliente(cliente);
    cuenta.setSaldo(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    return cuenta;

}


public String getIban() {
    return iban;
}

public void setIban(String iban) {
    this.iban = iban;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public BigDecimal getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}

public void setSaldo(BigDecimal saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}
public abstract void transferencia(BigDecimal cantidad, String IBANReceptor) throws MovimientoException, IbanException, CCCException;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  iban + ", DNI del cliente=" + cliente.getDNI() + ", saldo=" + saldo +" tipo de cuenta: "+ '}';
}
public void Ingreso(BigDecimal ingreso) throws MovimientoException{
    if (ingreso.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0) throw new MovimientoException("La cantidad a ingresar tiene que ser siempre positiva");
    this.saldo=saldo.add(ingreso);
}
public void retirada(BigDecimal retirada) throws MovimientoException{
    if(retirada.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0) throw new MovimientoException("la cantidad a retirar no puede ser inferior a 0");
    if(saldo.subtract(retirada).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0) throw new MovimientoException("La cantidad a retirar supera el saldo de la cuenta");
    this.saldo=saldo.subtract(retirada);
}
public static void recibirRegalo(Cuenta cuenta) {
    if (cuenta instanceof CuentaRegalito) {
        CuentaRegalito cuenta1=(CuentaRegalito)cuenta;
        if(cuenta1.isEntregado()){
            System.out.println("El regalo ya ha sido entregado");
        }else{
            cuenta1.recibirRegalito();
        }
}else{
        System.out.println("Este tipo de cuenta no ofrece regalito");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir "para usarlo en la clase Cuentas"? Tienes que pensar las clases como moldes que usarías para crear piezas (instancias) de objetos de ese tipo. Tu pregunta hace pensar que estás enfocando la POO al revés. Quizá si explicas mejor podremos entender y ayudarte adecuadamente.

Comment: ya la acabo de editar, muchas gracias!

Comment: Tu edición confirma mi sospecha de que no tienes claro el tema de la POO. Si tienes un arrayList de objetos de la clase `Cuenta` puedes usar todos sus métodos con cada elemento del array, no hay necesidad de liarse de la forma en que quieres liarte precisamente por no tener claro como funciona la POO. Sugiero que pongas las dos clases en la pregunta para revisarlas y sugerirte quizá alguna mejora al respecto.

Comment: acabo de añadir el codigo de las clases, muchas gracias por tu ayuda e interes!

Comment: Un trabalenguas, expresado en una organización confusa de tus clases... a ver si logro descifrar algo. Agradecería que uses el punto y aparte, ayuda a entender...

Comment: No logro descifrar tu lógica. Sugiero que agregues el método `main` y que intentes aclarar un poco, **con simplicidad y usando el punto y aparte**, la lógica que estás siguiendo. A veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema.

Comment: @alexnuñezperez La respuesta es simple. Agrégale al método `transferencia` un parámetro adicional, que sea de tipo `List<Cuenta>` y al momento de invocar el método, le pasas el objeto donde estén las cuentas. Ej: `transferencia(cuentas.getCuentas())`.

Comment: Aunque es raro que la clase `CuentaPlusTransfer` herede de Cuenta, porque CuentaPlusTransfer no es una cuenta ni un tipo de cuenta (por ejemplo, una cuenta de ahorro si pudiera heredar de Cuenta).